# Runtime errror. No entity manager found.Try annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.1, entitymanager

This is my code

```
import javax.persistence.Query;
import play.db.jpa.*;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;

import java.util.*;

@play.db.jpa.Transactional
public class GetS {

    public static List get() 
    {
        Query query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select * from product limit 1");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

I have already added Transactional but still error remain same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the @Transactional annotation on controller method.

```
class S extends Controller {
   ...
   @Transactional
   public static Result index() {
     ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Here more info: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJPA